# How to hide questions if id about user exist

Tags: html, database, hide

I have a question, doing some survey app, and got a problem. I'm fetching a team survey questions and users in a form. Like example team has 10 members. And has a survey. So same survey questions needs to be answered about every each user. I'm fetching in a form everything like:

UserId , UserName
Question1
Question2
Question3



NextUserId , NExtUserName
Question1
Question2
Question3

So some how I need to hide div with user name and questions, or just questions, if in database already exist answers in questions about this user. I mean, if I answered in survey about first user, next time when I open same survey, I should not see anymore same user and questions about it, if I already answered about him.

My database table where I place my answers and user id looks like:
There is

AnswerAboutUserId - **User ID, about which was answered**
MemberId - **who answered to questions**
Answer
AnswerId
QuestionaName

How can I do that?

below my controller and view

Controller:

```
public function viewSurvey($id)
{
    $object = DB::table('question')->where('survey_id' , '=', $id)->get();
    $date = Survey::where('surveyId' , '=', $id)->get();
    $teams = Auth::user()->teams;

    $survey = Survey::where('surveyId' , '=', $id)
        ->join('team','team.teamId', '=', 'survey.teamId')
        ->join('teammembersall','teammembersall.TeamId', '=', 'team.TeamId')
        ->join('users','users.id', '=', 'teammembersall.UserId')
        ->select('users.*')
        ->get();

    $questions = DB::table('answer')->get();

    return view('survey_details', ['object' => $object, 'date' => $date, 'teams' => $teams, 'survey' => $survey, 'questions' => $questions]);
}
```

This is my view blade:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <div class="container">
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                            <br>
                            <div style="display:none">
                            {{  $dates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
                            </div>

                                <div class="container-survey-logo">
                                    <img src={{url('/img/survey-banner.jpg')}} width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
                                    <div class="text-block-survey-date">
                                        @foreach($date as $dat)
                                        <h4>End date:</h4>
                                        <p>{{ $dat->ended_at}}</p>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="display:none;">
                                    @foreach($questions as $quest)
                                        <p>{{ $quest->answerAboutUserId}}</p>
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                                @if($dat->ended_at > $dates )
                                @if ($teams = Auth::user())
                                    <div class="survey-theme">
                                        @foreach($survey as $surv)
                                            @if($surv->id != Auth::user()->id)
                                            <form action="/confirmSurveyAnswers" method="post">
                                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                                <br>
                                                <div class="well well-lg">
                                                <h5>
                                                    Questions about member:
                                                    <h2><input style="border:none;background:none" name="surveyName" value="{{ $surv->name}}" readonly></h2>
                                                   <input style="border:none;background:none;display:none" name="surveyUserDataId" value="{{ $surv->id}}" readonly>
                                                 </h5>
                                                <br>
                                                @foreach($object as $object_each)
                                                                <input style="font-size:20px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAnswer" name="questionName[{{$object_each->id}}]" value="{!! $object_each->name !!}" readonly>
                                                        <div class="survey-questions">
                                                            <label class="radio-inline-text">
                                                                Not agree
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >1
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >2
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >3
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >4
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >5
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >6
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >7
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >8
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="9" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >9
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" value="10" name="QuestionsAnswers[{{$object_each->id}}]" >10
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label class="radio-inline-text">
                                                                 Fully agree
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                @endforeach
                                                    <div class="im-done-button">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">I'm Done</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                @endif
                                            </form>
                                            @endforeach
                                                <Br>
                                                @include('layouts.errors')

                                    </div>
                                    @else <h1>This is not your team survey</h1> @endif
                                     @else <h1>This survey ended</h1>  @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest adding a column to your database table which stores whether survey has been completed.

Comment: what do you mean? survey is not ended until mentioned date, I have stored data in survey table where date is mentioned. But I need some how to do not show questions about user, if answers about that user was already posted. Or what is your suggestion?

Comment: it's unclear how you're determining which questions have been answered, but you either query each answer and check for completeness or query a column which stores whether the survey has been completed